# Linking to page with auto-click for a specific category (out of multiple) - JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have developed a page that lists a bunch of divs, each containing some text content. At the top of the page are some buttons that allows me to filter which divs I want to view, based on a data-category. For example: I have listed all schools (all grade levels) at a school district, each in their own divs. When I click the 'Show High Schools' button, only the high school divs display below.

The filtering functionality works fine, but I'd like to be able to link to this page via another page and have the page auto click the appropriate category. I know how to setup an auto click for one button on page load. But what I'm trying to do is auto click a button depending on a specific category. So for example: I have a homepage that has the buttons 'High Schools', 'Middle Schools', and 'Elementary Schools'. When the user clicks the 'Middle Schools' button, they are taken to my filtering page, with only the Middle Schools being displayed. They can then click a 'Show All' button to reset the filtering system if needed.

[Live Link](https://www.conejousd.org/Enroll-CVUSD/Learn-More)

Again, the filtering works fine. I just don't know how to have links go to this page with an auto-click setup depending on category.

Comment: This question seems a bit broad without some context. It might help to show what you've built so far. You also might consider using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to control pages and content. Here's [an article](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/) that includes a [demo](http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/whiskers).

Comment: I know...I got ahead of myself without including a link to the project. I included a link now:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use query params "ex: [www.example.com/?category=high-school"](http://www.example.com/?category=high-school%22) redirect to another page and using the query params to display the required contents. It would be great if there is a code to view and help you out

Comment: I'll look into that now. Here is the page:
https://www.conejousd.org/Enroll-CVUSD/Learn-More

Thank you